# Get part of an multidimensional array into another one

Tags: php, arrays

I have a 3 dimensional array like this:

```
$entries[x][y][z]
```

- x will change depending on a query before, but i have the value in
  `$entries["count"]`.
- y is allways 'uid'
- z is allways 0

**How can i get the values of** `$entries[0]['uid'][0]` **to** `$entries[$entries["count"]]`['uid'][0] **in a new (one-dimensional) array? I want to store it in a session-variable.**

I tried doing it like this:

```
$_SESSION['array_uid'] = $entries[]['uid'][0];
```

But that´s just wrong syntax i guess, as it produces this error:

> Fatal error: Cannot use [] for reading

Comment: Your first entry is empty, as you state [] - $entries["count"] I mean by that is null.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through $entries.
Or specify a value for entries when you assign the value.

```
$_SESSION['array_uid'] = $entries[$entries["count"]]['uid'][0];
```

or

```
$_SESSION['array_uid'] = $entries[0]['uid'][0];
```